# what is the diference to output superscript using the below two methods in html

Tags: html

in html, i can use both `&trade` and `<sup></sup>` to output superscript. Then, what is the difference between '`&trade`' and '`<sup></sup>`'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&trade;` is a single character, whereas `<sup></sup>` changes the way "normal" characters are displayed.

Using `<sup>TM</sup>` is just displaying the two letters `T` and `M` using superscript text layout, whereas `&trade;` is the [Unicode Character 'TRADE MARK SIGN' (U+2122)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm).

Practically speaking:

- `&trade;` might not survive copy-and-paste across different documents (given how broken some applications are with respect to Unicode).
- It's not necessarily available in every font you might use.
- Anyone searching for "TM" won't find `&trade;` (unless the software they're using is clever about that specific case).

Answer (score 1):

with `<sup>` you can add any superscript. `&trade` is for TM only

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/4quqt/

Answer (score 0):

`&trade;` is the entity for the trademark symbol ™. `<sup>` is for superscript in general. You can include any text at all in between the `<sup>` tags.

As far as ™ vs `<sup>tm</sup>` goes, the former should use the correct trademark glyph of the font you are using or the fallback. It was more than likely designed by the type designer to look optimal, while with `<sup>` the browser more than likely just scaled the t and m characters down. The former will have better spacing, look clearer at small sizes, and be generally more aesthetically pleasing.